# How to access class field variable inside all methods from toString twin toStrung?

Tags: java, class, static, field, static-methods

Once upon modifying the above with *static* modifiers, line 16 requires the following syntax: 
getLegs();toStrung();

//I think this is essentially printing the last called method updating class field variable toString. For example, to do setLegs();toStrung(); prints setLegs()'s toString.

Question: How should one access a shared field within methods? What if I included it into the constructor? Ideally, I want the code to look like getLegs().toStrung() and for toString to be a clean slate for every method.

My answer: I think a seperate instance of String toString inside each method works to get a clean slate appeal, but the syntax doesn't make sense. I know it is about my design. I think a solution would be a new class, but this returns to the same conflict that relates to the class field variable.

```
public class Dog{
public String toString; 

public Dog(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public int getLegs(){
    toString = "Dog has " + legs + " legs.";
    return legs; 
}

public int setLegs(int legs){
    toString = getName() + "'s legs have changed from " 
                         + getLegs() + " to " + legs + "."; 
    this.legs = legs;
    return this.legs; 
}

public void toStrung(){
    System.out.println(Dog.toString);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Dog Dundt = new Dog("Dundt"); 
    Dundt.getLegs();
    Dundt.toStrung();                   

}
```

Comment: You just call the class and the Method like this `Dog.toStrung();`

Comment: You're not calling `toStrung()` on an instance of `Dog` so how could it print out any data from `this`? `this` has no meaning in a static context, so you either need to change `getToString()` so that it doesn't operate on an instance, or you need to call `toStrung()` on an instance of `Dog`, which I suspect is what you actually want to do.

Comment: That is what I wanted to do. I think the conflict arose from an unclear purpose in design and capability.

Comment: This new version still seems a little odd to me - you're going to hit problems if you have more than one `Dog` instance. `static` is a pain in the backside when you're relatively new to the concept, and the temptation is just to slap `static` in front of stuff until it compiles - which in practice is rarely the right thing to do. Remove the `static` from the declaration of `toString` and from the signature of `toStrung()`, then change your main method so that it calls: `Dundt.toStrung()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) toString() should not be a static member.

2) getLegs() should not have the side effect of changing the member String toString.

3) There should not be a member variable String toString.

4) toString() should return a String.

5) name needs to be a member.

6) legs needs to be a member.

7) toString() should generate the string from the members at run time.

8) You do not need to explicitly call toString() in main. Simply passing the instance of Dog to println will call it for you.

9) It is good practice to annotate methods you are overriding with the @Override annotation. toString() is a member of Object and you are overriding Object.

```
public class Dog{
    private String name;
    private int legs = 4;

    public Dog(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getLegs(){
        return legs; 
    }

    public int setLegs(int legs){
        this.legs = legs;
        return this.legs; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Dog is called " + name + " it has " + legs + " legs."; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dog dundt = new Dog("Dundt"); 
        System.out.println(dundt);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the original source code, the toString method is actually getToString() returning a String. Besides the point, it is part of my design that methods change String toString to serve the function of printing what is happening, without having to use a System.out.println("stuff changed"). I like your way of overriding toString(), but I am trying to find a way that stores a String of changes even in getLegs() and setLegs(legs) and prints it when a method calls it.

If I called getLegs().toString(), it should print "Dog has" + getLegs() + " legs."

Comment: toString() means something quite particular in java. I do not think it is a good idea to change its behavior. If you really want the behavior you describe then I strongly suggest not calling your method toString()

Comment: Generally speaking it is good practice to ensure that your get methods are "idempotent" which is to say they should not change the internal state of your objects.